# IntelliJ does not find scss import from stylePreprocessorOptions includePaths

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, sass

IntelliJ 2019.2.2 Ultimate does not find scss imports from `stylePreprocessorOptions` -  `includePaths`

dir structure

[image]

`angular.json`

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": ["apps/client/src/branding/default/css"]
}
```

IntelliJ error message when I try to import the file:

[image]

I found some old related IntelliJ issues, which have been fixed long time agon (in version 2018.2):

- [WEB-28376](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28376)
- [WEB-32648](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32648)

Note: the application works fine - but IntelliJ shows an error.

Any idea, what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 more issues: [WEB-40236](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40236) and [WEB-40457](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40457); both are fixed in upcoming 2019.2.3

Comment: I can confirm that this works in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3

Answer (score 0):

You can also click right button and Mark directory as → Source root
[image]